# Match all values between two dates within same column in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery, excel-2016

I was thinking it will be easier to solve this, but I failed...

In screenshot below is dummy example of my data where Column A is in Date/Time format showing time as hh:mm:ss and there are lot of values. Column B corresponds to pressure change withing a date, minute, hour.

On the right side where Column F and G is where I need an assistance, as you see in column F the Date is paired within column (start/end date) what corresponds to the column G (start/stop).
I would like to have all measurements from Column B that are between those specific dates (for instance 19.02.2021 12:10 and 19.02.2020 12:47), that means like 37 minutes. And I need for all date pairs (start / end date).

Original data...almost 500 examples:

```
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020 01:17   | 31 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   01:18 | 31 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   01:19 | 31 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   01:20 | 32 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   01:21 | 32 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   01:22 | 33 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   01:23 | 33 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   01:24 | 33 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   01:25 | 34 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   01:26 | 34 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   01:27 | 35 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   01:28 | 35 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   01:29 | 36 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   01:30 | 36 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   01:31 | 37 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   01:32 | 37 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   01:33 | 38 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   01:34 | 38 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   01:35 | 39 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   01:36 | 39 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   01:37 | 40 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   01:38 | 40 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   01:39 | 40 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   01:40 | 41 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   01:41 | 41 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   01:42 | 42 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   01:43 | 42 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   01:44 | 43 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   01:45 | 43 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   01:46 | 44 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   01:47 | 44 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   01:48 | 45 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   01:49 | 45 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   01:50 | 46 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   01:51 | 46 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   01:52 | 47 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   01:53 | 47 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   01:54 | 48 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   01:55 | 48 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   01:56 | 49 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   01:57 | 49 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   01:58 | 50 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   01:59 | 50 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:00 | 50 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:01 | 51 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:02 | 51 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:03 | 52 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:04 | 52 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:05 | 52 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:06 | 53 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:07 | 53 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:08 | 53 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:09 | 54 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:10 | 54 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:12 | 54 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:13 | 55 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:14 | 55 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:15 | 55 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:16 | 55 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:17 | 55 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:18 | 56 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:19 | 56 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:20 | 56 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:21 | 56 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:22 | 56 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:23 | 56 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:24 | 57 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:25 | 57 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:26 | 57 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:27 | 57 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:28 | 57 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:29 | 57 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:30 | 57 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:31 | 57 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:32 | 57 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:33 | 57 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:34 | 57 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:35 | 57 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:36 | 57 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:37 | 57 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:38 | 57 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:39 | 57 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:40 | 57 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:41 | 57 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:42 | 57 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:43 | 57 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:44 | 57 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:45 | 57 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:46 | 57 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:47 | 57 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:48 | 57 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:49 | 57 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:50 | 57 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:51 | 57 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:52 | 57 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:53 | 57 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:54 | 57 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:55 | 57 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:56 | 56 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020 02:57   | 56 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:58 | 56 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   02:59 | 56 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:00 | 56 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:01 | 56 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:02 | 56 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:03 | 56 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:04 | 56 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:05 | 56 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:06 | 55 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:07 | 55 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:08 | 55 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:09 | 55 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:10 | 55 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:11 | 55 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:12 | 55 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:13 | 55 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:14 | 55 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:15 | 55 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:16 | 55 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:17 | 55 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:18 | 54 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:19 | 54 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:20 | 54 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:21 | 54 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:22 | 54 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:23 | 54 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:24 | 54 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:25 | 54 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:26 | 54 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:27 | 54 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:28 | 53 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:29 | 53 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:30 | 53 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:31 | 53 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:32 | 53 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:33 | 53 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:34 | 53 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:35 | 53 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:36 | 53 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:37 | 53 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:38 | 52 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:39 | 52 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:40 | 52 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:41 | 52 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:42 | 52 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:43 | 52 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:44 | 52 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:45 | 52 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:46 | 52 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:47 | 52 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:48 | 52 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:49 | 52 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:50 | 51 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:51 | 51 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:52 | 51 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:53 | 51 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:54 | 51 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:55 | 51 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:56 | 51 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:57 | 51 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:58 | 51 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   03:59 | 51 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:00 | 51 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:01 | 50 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:02 | 50 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:03 | 50 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:04 | 50 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:05 | 50 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:06 | 50 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:07 | 50 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:08 | 50 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:09 | 50 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:10 | 50 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:11 | 50 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:12 | 49 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:13 | 49 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:14 | 49 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:15 | 49 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:16 | 49 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:17 | 49 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:18 | 49 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:19 | 49 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:20 | 49 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:21 | 49 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:22 | 49 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:23 | 48 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:24 | 48 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:25 | 48 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:26 | 48 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:27 | 48 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:28 | 48 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:29 | 48 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:30 | 48 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:31 | 48 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:32 | 48 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:33 | 48 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:34 | 48 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:35 | 47 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:36 | 47 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:37 | 47 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:38 | 47 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:39 | 47 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:40 | 47 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:41 | 47 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:42 | 47 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:43 | 47 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:44 | 47 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:45 | 47 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:46 | 46 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:47 | 46 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:48 | 46 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:49 | 46 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:50 | 46 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:51 | 46 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:52 | 46 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:53 | 46 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:54 | 46 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:55 | 46 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:56 | 45 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:57 | 45 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:58 | 45 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   04:59 | 45 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:00 | 45 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:01 | 45 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:02 | 45 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:03 | 45 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:04 | 45 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:05 | 45 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:06 | 44 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:07 | 44 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:08 | 44 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:09 | 44 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:10 | 44 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:11 | 44 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:12 | 44 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:14 | 44 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:15 | 44 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:16 | 44 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:17 | 44 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:18 | 43 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:19 | 43 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:20 | 43 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:21 | 43 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:22 | 43 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:23 | 43 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:24 | 43 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:25 | 43 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:26 | 43 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:27 | 43 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:28 | 42 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:29 | 42 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:30 | 42 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:31 | 42 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:32 | 42 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:33 | 42 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:34 | 42 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:35 | 42 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:36 | 42 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:37 | 41 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:38 | 41 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:39 | 41 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:40 | 41 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:41 | 41 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:42 | 41 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:43 | 41 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:44 | 41 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:45 | 41 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:46 | 40 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:47 | 40 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:48 | 40 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:49 | 40 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:50 | 40 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:51 | 40 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:52 | 40 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:53 | 40 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:54 | 40 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:55 | 39 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:56 | 39 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:57 | 39 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:58 | 39 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   05:59 | 39 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   06:00 | 39 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   06:01 | 39 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   06:02 | 39 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   06:03 | 39 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   06:04 | 39 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   06:05 | 39 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   06:06 | 38 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   06:07 | 38 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   06:08 | 38 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   06:09 | 38 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   06:10 | 38 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   06:11 | 38 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   06:12 | 38 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   06:13 | 38 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   06:14 | 38 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   06:15 | 38 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   06:16 | 38 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   06:17 | 37 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   06:18 | 37 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   06:19 | 37 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   06:20 | 37 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   06:21 | 37 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   06:22 | 37 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   06:23 | 37 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   06:24 | 37 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   06:25 | 37 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   06:26 | 37 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   06:27 | 36 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   06:28 | 36 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   06:29 | 36 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   06:30 | 36 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   06:31 | 36 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   06:32 | 36 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   06:33 | 36 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   06:34 | 36 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   06:35 | 36 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   06:36 | 35 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   06:37 | 35 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   06:38 | 35 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   06:39 | 35 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   06:40 | 35 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   06:41 | 35 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   06:42 | 35 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   06:43 | 35 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   06:44 | 35 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   06:45 | 35 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   06:46 | 35 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
| 19.02.2020   06:47 | 35 |  |  |  |
+--------------------+----+--+--+--+
```

I tried with:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/($A:$A<=F2)/($A:$A>=F2),$B:$B)
```

**This is output what I would like to have according to the date pairs in Column F.**

```
19.02.2020 12:10    33
19.02.2020 12:11    135
19.02.2020 12:12    199
19.02.2020 12:13    198
19.02.2020 12:14    198
19.02.2020 12:15    198
19.02.2020 12:16    198
19.02.2020 12:17    198
19.02.2020 12:18    198
19.02.2020 12:19    198
19.02.2020 12:20    198
19.02.2020 12:21    198
19.02.2020 12:22    198
19.02.2020 12:23    198
19.02.2020 12:24    198
19.02.2020 12:25    198
19.02.2020 12:26    198
19.02.2020 12:27    198
19.02.2020 12:28    198
19.02.2020 12:29    198
19.02.2020 12:30    198
19.02.2020 12:31    198
19.02.2020 12:32    198
19.02.2020 12:33    197
19.02.2020 12:34    198
19.02.2020 12:35    197
19.02.2020 12:36    197
19.02.2020 12:37    197
19.02.2020 12:38    197
19.02.2020 12:39    197
19.02.2020 12:40    197
19.02.2020 12:41    197
19.02.2020 12:42    197
19.02.2020 12:43    197
19.02.2020 12:44    197
19.02.2020 12:45    197
19.02.2020 12:46    197
19.02.2020 12:47    197
02.04.2020 11:48     87
02.04.2020 11:49    181
02.04.2020 11:50    198
02.04.2020 11:51    198
02.04.2020 11:52    198
```

- 
- 
- 
- 

```
02.04.2020 12:25    198
```

[image]

Comment: Your first screenshot doesn't show any times in the range 12:10 to 12:44 so it's difficult for us to see where the values in the second screenshot are coming from.

Comment: Is it possible to have these as text  or link to sheet so we don't have to to type them in? See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @TomSharpe Sorry but the data has over 100k of values... thats not gonna work easily.  It is saved from the system every minute...

Comment: Sounds like there is a good case for selecting part of the data or creating some artificial test data just so contributors can test their solutions

Comment: To reinforce what @TomSharpe wrote, create a sample of data and an example of what you want as results **from that data**.  Post in text format so we can easily copy/paste it for testing. perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables).  I don't think it is that difficult a problem, but without a relevant example, it is hard to craft a solution.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Updated...it is the output I would like to have

Comment: @DávidLaczkó  Hmm man, I put an output what I wanted to achieve. You got start date, you got end date and thousands of values (measurements). I wanted to have specific values that are within start/end date.

Comment: All I see is what you want for results.  I don't see the (more important) sample of data from which it is derived. Without that, your desired results are not useful.  Again, please post the data sample as TEXT which can be copy/pasted.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld  I added, but I mean...they are the same data as I added in my post....I cant copy 5k of different data. I managed to do 500 maybe...the app crashes. I hope this helps..I dont have other data actually

Comment: Is it that you want to use columns `F:G` as a complex filter for `A:B`?  With the results in a single pair of columns?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Yea man...simple as that....I just need an idea how to do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for a method to filter your data table by multiple parameters -- those times from start to stop time as listed in col F.

**Assumptions**

- datetimes are listed at one minute intervals, on the minute, as you show.
- Column `F` has start/stop times listed in that order

***Edit:** Original assumption of datetimes being at one minute interval, on the minute, incorrect.  Real data shows times to the **second***

**Method**

- Create a list of the relevant time stamps from column F
- Apply that list to the date/time column from your original data as a filter

***Edit: Code modified for possible speed up***
***Edit2: Code modified as actual data has time with a one second granularity***
***Edit 3: edited to account for possible multiple "starts" in a row, retaining the last***

**M Code**

```
let

//Be sure to change the table names in the Source= and Source2= lines to be the actual table names from your workbook
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="P7_data"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date/Time", type datetime}, {"P7 [mbar]", Int64.Type}}),
       
//get start/stop times table
    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="TStmp"]}[Content],
    typeIt = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source2, {"Date/Time", type datetime}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(typeIt, each ([#"Date/Time"] <> null)),

//if multiple "starts" in a row, remove all except the last
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "NextLineStart", 
        each if Text.Contains([Info],"start", Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) = true 
                and Text.Contains(#"Added Index"[Info]{[Index]+1},"start",Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) = true 
            then "delete" 
            else null),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([NextLineStart] = null)),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows1",{"Index", "NextLineStart"}),

//create a list of all the relevant start/stop times
     filterTimes = List.Combine(
                        List.Generate(
                            ()=> [times = List.DateTimes(#"Removed Columns1"[#"Date/Time"]{0}, 
                                                        Duration.TotalSeconds(#"Removed Columns1"[#"Date/Time"]{1}-#"Removed Columns1"[#"Date/Time"]{0})+1,
                                                        #duration(0,0,0,1)), IDX = 0],
                            each [IDX] < Table.RowCount(#"Removed Columns1"),
                            each [times = List.DateTimes(#"Removed Columns1"[#"Date/Time"]{[IDX]+2}, 
                                                        Duration.TotalSeconds(#"Removed Columns1"[#"Date/Time"]{[IDX]+3}-#"Removed Columns1"[#"Date/Time"]{[IDX]+2})+1,
                                                        #duration(0,0,0,1)), IDX = [IDX]+2],
                            each [times]
                                    )
                            ),

//filter the table using the list
filterTimesCol = Table.FromList(filterTimes,Splitter.SplitByNothing()),
filteredTable = Table.Join(#"Changed Type","Date/Time",filterTimesCol,"Column1",JoinKind.Inner),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(filteredTable,{"Column1"})

in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

*Note that the dates below are in MDY format*
**Original Data**
[image]

**Filter**
[image]

**Results**
[image]

Comment: That was a good point, but I don't get something, why as a last step is "filtered table"? It takes exceptionally long to load and crashes mostly Excel...But previous step (filter Times) is a good point, but I only need P7 (pressure) additionally.

Comment: So again, "filterTimes" step is good, but I only need P7 column additionally that corresponds to the Date/Time from the List and that's it. There are my values what I need. Later I will do some tweaks on my own...

Comment: @Mirza You show **two** columns as your desired result in your question.  In any event, feel free to modify to suit whatever it is that you really want. I guess I can't figure that out from what you've presented. I can probably speed up the last step, though.

Comment: Well output what I have is wrong using the query. But I tell you, in your query step, I just need small modification where the "filter times" step is.., there is only date/time what is correct, but I need additional column for P7.

Comment: @Mirza I have modified the code to possibly speed up the final step.  Please check that part and let me know.   If all you want is the P7 column, feel free to also delete the Date/Time column at the end.  But that is NOT what you show in your question.

Comment: @Mirza By the way, if the query still runs slowly, we can try to buffer the list and the table.  Let me know.

Comment: Check the file...it doesnt work as I wanted...it is fast thats fine but the output is wrong..I sent you whole file. You will see what I wanna and your PQ output. 

I need all values that are within one date/time pair. 19.02 12:10 till 19.02 12:47...thats many values as you can see in excel file... and for all pairs the same thing.

Comment: @Mirza Unable to access file

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aYhpwxOWleU6CB-J2fFCfaYRROC2rzQD/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Check it now..I changed privacy

Comment: @Mirza The problem is that you did not properly represent your data.  Take a look at my **Assumptions** in my answer.  Your times in your ***actual*** data are **NOT** at one minute intervals on the minute.  Hence, no matching.  Also, do you only want results returned for the first two pairs which you have in Bold?  Or for ALL of the start/stop pairs?

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. We could avoid long typing if I sent my data at the very beginning. Well for ALL pairs I am looking to have values, exactly as it is in Excel file, not only bolded ones. Can you make them to be minute interval, no seconds? Then I will have all values... thanks a lot man if you will have time for that.

Comment: @Mirza Easier to just create the `FilterTimes` list to be at one second intervals.

Comment: Ah finally :=) Thanks a lot man. This is exactly what I needed..works as it should be!

Comment: Expression.Error: There weren't enough elements in the enumeration to complete the operation: List

I tried to change the path but it gave me this error. It worked good with one file and report, but I wanted to apply same calculations on another files but now It doesnt work...every other query uploads nicely but only one with this Start/Stop no... any idea maybe?

Comment: @Mirza maybe you have duplicate times in data? But without data sample to reproduce error cannot be certain.

Comment: No duplicates...similar data as up. Here is the data set so you can check witth query again...

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j6P1vlD8ie42OV6DTrpw2qG2rS1zyvu2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: and by "Filter Times" Step it gives me an error...even tough rest of steps are fine (final too), but it can load on the sheet....

Comment: @Mirza Your filter column has more starts than stops.  Note that there are an odd number of rows.  In addition, note that `1/5/2021  1:23:47 PM  Start leaktest C2.` is immediately followed by another start time.  Clean up your filter column, and the query works as it should

Comment: It is not functioning..I dont have any filter on it... Well "stop" in this case is "finished"...There is no filter "stop". Somehow it doesnt match values as it should be...
Do they need to have exactly the same "timing" for match? for instance if pressure started at 17:01 and the info "start" was on 17:00?

Comment: @Mirza I thought what you wanted and what I have been providing were the values in your first table that existed between each stop/start pair in your second table. In order to do that you must have **pairs**. That implies an even number of times in your second table. If that is not what you want then we have been barking up the wrong tree for a very long time.

Comment: Oh my friend.. as I see yes. BecAuse I realised today it will be different.. or not exactly the timing..  is there some workaround here on this query? To give me good results?

Comment: @Mirza Not unless you define **exactly** what you want to do when you don't have a stop time for each start, or vice-versa.

Comment: I will write back in day-two. I think I found some issue in my data set actually...will write again, need to chill one day at least on weekend! Thanks for swift answers!

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1UCBGwwqJ2_XkEZkUlLq-cKTxHZAnZ0W2?usp=sharing

I uploaded new Test version of my data, where you can check queries, one is working and another not. Similar data, but I don't get it what is a problem.

Check by "not working" query step "filterTimes" it is yellowed [List]...

Comment: @Mirza That link does not lead to a file.  How many rows are there in the entries in each dataset in columns `F:G`?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ekcsoR6OXCdkml5ZDT4LwEquNX-bqCI-/view?usp=sharing

Now?

87 entries...

Comment: @Mirza That is why it will not work. See my comments above.  You do not have matching pairs in columns F:G

Comment: @Mirza In particular, `Sheet1!F44` contains a "start time".  But the next row also contains a `start time`.  Therefore a routine that returns the entries between each start/stop time fails.  You have not stated what you want to do in this instance.

Comment: Ah I see now, didnt expect that there will double values as you found out. Is there a possibility to remove duplicate (first instance value for instance and leave the second) because as I see it started to count from second one properly.

Comment: I cant predict those values actually, only to make some step where it will filter out "doubles". 
Our systems are 99% accurate in data logging, but as I see it is giving some extra values.

Comment: @Mirza will all the start times (and none of the end times) contain the word **start**?

Comment: Yes, it is so programmed. Start and Finished (aka. end)

Comment: @Mirza OK, I've edited the code again to remove all except the last "start" if there are multiple "start"'s in a row. That works on your example.

Comment: Amazing man, it works as it should be. Great handling with Power Query...I mean, I am far far away from that level. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I saw you helped me that time with Power Query, start/stop time and so on (check the code). I got an issue that pops-up but I think I know why: Expression.Error: The 'increment' argument is out of range.
Details:
    0.00:00:01    

It is obviously that there is no exact matching pairs (it can differ in seconds). Could you somehow adjust the Query to skip or look for next matching values, if not exactly in seconds but then in minutes if it doesnt find suitable...so as an IF condition. You will need to scroll a bit what we talked and what was an issue.. thanks a lot!